# Maximizing a function of multiple variables WITHOUT lagrange multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

My prof explicitly told us to solve this problem without using lagrange multiplier. [image]

my attempt at this gives me a saddle point instead via the 2nd partials test. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: You should typeset your question, rather than posting a picture, and also use words to explain your attempt. What are $x$, $y$, $z$ and so on?

Comment: z is radius of circle, x and y are dimensions of rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **you're missing the boundary.**

Your work so far is perfectly correct, and it shows that the only stationary (critical) point is not a local extreme value. But the condition that the total length is $100$, along with the the fact that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are lengths and thus cannot be negative, define a certain domain of this function. And when finding the absolute maximum or minimum of a continuous functions on a closed, bounded domain, you must examine both the critical points in the interior of the domain (which you did) and what happens on the boundary of the domain (which you didn't).

The three conditions that you have to set up are $y\ge0$, $z\ge0$, and $x=50-y-\pi z\ge0$. They define a closed triangular region in the $yz$-plane. Examine the boundary of the triangle (its three sides) to find the absolute maximum of the function — I bet it's somewhere on the boundary.

Comment: OHHHH I didn't even think of that. Thx for the reminder.

Comment: @Prandals: You're welcome! If my answer helped, you can vote on it... and maybe even accept it...

Comment: ok so it turns  out that one of the corners of the boundary is the maximizing dimensions ( 0,0, (50/pi) )   where (x,y,z)   . Thanks again for the help

Comment: @Prandals: Yep, that's correct. Geometrically, this says that the most symmetric shape is the most efficient one -- so he should just make one big circle and forget about a rectangle! :-)